# Duvida de como armazenar o ID de um registro trazido do banco, para uso posterior no PHP?

Tags: php, html, select, id

Como eu poderia armazenar o `ID` de cada registro, e o `ID_PESSOAS` ao passar pelo `while ($exibe = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dados)` para que futuramente ao o usuário clicar no botão "ver vagas" eu saiba qual dos registros trazidos pelo `select` foi clicado pelo usuário, e então eu possa levá-lo para uma outra página com todos os dados referentes a linha do registro em questão no MySQL.

Vou deixar a parte do código essensial para entendimento a seguir

Selecionando dados do banco

```
session_start();

include('../conexao.php');

$redirecionar = $_SESSION['email'];

$consulta = "SELECT * FROM vagas_emprego
         LEFT JOIN pessoas ON `ID_PESSOAS` = `PESSOAS_ID_PESSOAS`
         WHERE `status` = 'O' AND `ramo` = 'Produção'
   UNION ALL             
        SELECT * FROM habilidades_candidatos
        LEFT JOIN pessoas ON `ID_PESSOAS` = `PESSOAS_ID_PESSOAS`
        WHERE `status` = 'O'AND `ramo` = 'Produção'";
$dados = mysqli_query($CONN, $consulta);
$row = mysqli_num_rows($dados);
```

Exibindo os dados

```
 <div class="col-md-10 ml-auto mr-auto"><br>
        <?php while ($exibe = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dados)) { ?>
            <div class="card border-dark mb-3">
                <div class="card-header">
                    Produção | Portal de Empregos
                </div>
                <div class="md-form">
                    <h4 class="card-title"><?php echo " " . $exibe["TITULO_VAGA"] . " | " . $exibe["ID_VAGAS_EMPREGO"]; ?></h4>
                    <textarea readonly style="background-color: white; resize: none" id="form7" class="md-textarea form-control" rows="10"> <?php echo $exibe["DESCRICAO_VAGA"]; ?></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                    <center><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Ver Vaga</a></center>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php }
```

Comment: No elemento `<a>` você informa a URL da outra página; basta passar o valor do id pela query string, ficando algo como `/exibir.php?id=1`

Comment: seu `SELECT` não seria assim? SELECT * FROM vagas_emprego
             LEFT JOIN pessoas ON `vagas_emprego`.ID_PESSOAS = `pessoas` .PESSOAS_ID_PESSOAS
             WHERE `status` = 'O' AND `ramo` = 'Produção

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar as sessões do PHP para armazenar cada item clicado.

Após obter todos os dados do banco, crie a variável de sessão responsável por armazenar todos os itens clicados.

```
//...
$row = mysqli_num_rows($dados);

$_SESSION['itemsClicked'] = (empty($_SESSION['itemsClicked'])) ? array() : $_SESSION['itemsClicked'];
```

Com a variável de sessão criada precisamos adicionar as vagas que foram clicadas. Isso pode ser feito na página de visualização da vaga e, como não foi informado qual é o arquivo, vamos supor que a descrição da vaga esteja no arquivo `vaga.php`.

Na listagem das vagas vamos atribuir o `id` da vaga no atributo `href`:

```
<div class="card-footer">
    <center><a href="vagas.php?id=<?php echo $exibe['ID_VAGAS_EMPREGO'] ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Ver Vaga</a></center>
</div>
```

No arquivo `vagas.php` atribuíremos o `id` da vaga clicada a nossa variável de sessão.

```
//vagas.php

$vagaId = $_GET['id'];
if (isset($vagaId) && $vagaId != '') {
    $_SESSION['itemsClicked'][] = $vagaId;
}
```

Agora basta utilizar a variável de sessão  para fazer as manipulações necessárias.

**EDIT**

Para armazenar os dois valores e utilizá-los como parâmetro é necessário fazer uma pequena modificação nos exemplos que passei.

Primeiro é necessário adicionar mais um valor na query string que será o `ID_PESSOAS`.

```
<div class="card-footer">
    <?php $queryString = 'id=' . $exibe['ID_VAGAS_EMPREGO'] . '&idPessoas=' . $exibe['ID_PESSOAS']; ?>
    <center><a href="vagas.php?<?php echo $queryString ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Ver Vaga</a></center>
</div>
```

> Coloquei o conteúdo da query string em uma variável para maior legibilidade.

No arquivo `vagas.php` é necessário identificar e armazenar o novo valor fornecido através da requisição.

```
//vagas.php

$vagaId = $_GET['id'];
$idPessoas = $_GET['idPessoas'];

//Realize as validações da string como mostrado acima

$_SESSION['itemsClicked'][] = [
    'id' => $vagaId,
    'idPessoas' => $idPessoas
];
```

Agora cada item do array terá um array contendo o id e o id das pessoas.

Comment: Resposta perfeita, você é fod*a, obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @Bianca, dê nada! 

Comment: mais uma perguntinha se não for muito incomodo, e como eu faria para passar 2 atributos nesse caso?

Comment: @Bianca, quais são esses dois atributos?

Comment: devido algumas necessidades precisei mudar meu select para:          
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM vagas_emprego
             LEFT JOIN pessoas ON `ID_PESSOAS` = `PESSOAS_ID_PESSOAS`
             WHERE `status` = 'O' AND `ramo` = 'Administração'
UNION ALL             
            SELECT * FROM habilidades_candidatos
            LEFT JOIN pessoas ON `ID_PESSOAS` = `PESSOAS_ID_PESSOAS`
            WHERE `status` = 'O'AND `ramo` = 'Administração'";

Comment: E nessa situação por estar fazendo dois selects não posso apenas pegar o ID do registro pois na outra tabela pode haver um registro com o mesmo ID, então preciso pegar o ID_PESSOAS e enviar juntamente com o outro ID que já havia me ajudado, que eu sei que assim não haverá duplicação de registros na hora de mostrar!

Comment: Faz um **edit** na questão que atualizo a resposta pra vc... E se a resposta te ajudou não esquece daquela marcação de melhor resposta e aquele upzinho pra fortalecer kkk

Comment: Certo vou alterar o select

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi precisa somente do id e armazenar em uma variável, vou dar exemplos com PDO mas peço que introduza no mysqli como deseja.

Exemplo de listagem de todos registros:

```
$consulta = $this->query("SELECT * FROM vagas_emprego"); // Consulta sem relacionamento
```

Continuação dessa consulta sem relacionamento

```
//Validação se tem registros listados caso o rowCount retorn maior que zero é por que ele tem registros
if($consulta->rowCount() > 0){
    $array = $consulta->fetchAll();
}
//retorno de todos dados
return $array;
```

Armazenando dados do retorno de todos registros:

```
//loop para listar todos registros do banco e atribuindo a uma váriavel com index vazio assim fara index de 0 até ... 
foreach($array as $dados){
    $id[] = $dados['id'];
}
// retornando em indexs cada id de cada registro
return $id;
```

Caso precise de dados relacionado é só fazer com INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN como mostra seu exemplo.